# How to add `react-native-reanimated/plugin` to `babel.config.js`?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I'm trying to upgrade `react-native-reanimated` from `v1.13.3` to `v2.0.1`. In the [installation instructions](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/2.x/fundamentals/installation) they say to add `react-native-reanimated/plugin` to your `babel.config.js` as follows:

```
  module.exports = {
    presets: [
      ...
    ],
    plugins: [
      ...
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ],
  };
```

Currently my `babel.config.js` looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  env: {
    production: {
      plugins: [
        'react-native-paper/babel'
      ],
    },
  }
};
```

If I add it like this:

```
plugins: [
            'react-native-paper/babel'
            'react-native-reanimated/plugin'
          ],
```

I get this error: `Transform's input file does not exist: <project>/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/react-native-reanimated-65.aar. (See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158753935)`

How should I add it instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
module.exports = {
   presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
   env: {
      production: {
         plugins: [
           'react-native-paper/babel'
         ],
      },
   },
   plugins: [
        'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
   ],
};
```

Comment: I have this but react native is completely ignoring the babel.config.js for some reason. I can add complete garbage to the file and it still builds and runs just fine.