# Upgrade to React-Native 0.72.3 from 0.69

Tags: react-native

I am badly struck with below two errors below and cannot find solution anywhere from last 3 days -

ERROR  Error: [Reanimated] The native part of Reanimated doesn't seem to be initialized. This could be caused by

- not rebuilding the app after installing or upgrading Reanimated
- trying to run Reanimated on an unsupported platform
- running in a brownfield app without manually initializing the native library, js engine: hermes
  LOG  Running "deepmart" with {"rootTag":71}
  ERROR  Invariant Violation: "deepmart" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

I tried everything from clearing cache to re-adding node-modules and also updating reanimated package but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Reanimated library is always very finicky. The first thing I would suggest is to remove it entirely from your project and then see if you can get React-Native running without it. After you've succeeded in that, then trying reintroducing Reanimated.

I've also found this suggestion to help when working with *certain* Reanimated version: [How to add `react-native-reanimated/plugin` to `babel.config.js`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75549528/how-to-add-react-native-reanimated-plugin-to-babel-config-js)

Comment: Hii Maxwell, thanks for your response, I already tried your suggestion earlier but still it is not working. Also, my babel.config.js is configured properly.